# Atualizar registros de uma tabela usando valores de outra tabela

Tags: mysql

Preciso fazer um update em uma tabela com o valor de outra tabela e são muitos registros então por estou fazendo dessa forma, mas a minha query não está dando certo:

```
UPDATE produtos SET produtos.fornecedor = movimentacao.Fornecedor FROM produtos,
movimentacao WHERE produtos.codigo = movimentacao.Codigo ORDER BY movimentacao.Data DESC LIMIT 1
```

> ERRO : #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'FROM produtos, movimentacao WHERE produtos.codigo =
>   movimentacao.Codigo ORDER B' at line 3

Alguém sabe como resolver esse erro de sintaxe?

Comment: Deu uma resposta geral pelo que você perguntou. Se der mais detalhes sobre a necessidade do limit e do order, posso tentar pensar em algo melhor.

Comment: @Bacco O `ORDER BY` é que eu quero atualizar com o valor do registro mais recente e o `LIMIT` para limitar a o ultimo valor mais recente

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Acredito que o que você queira seja isso

```
UPDATE Campeonato 
SET Nome =(SELECT Nome FROM Time WHERE Campeonato_Id= Campeonato.Id AND Position = '1')
WHERE
Ano ='2013'
```

No exemplo acima eu estou atualizando o `Nome` de **todos** os `Campeonatos` do **Ano** de `2013` para o `Nome` do `Time` correspondente ao **Campeonato** e que ocupa a **primeira** posição.

Não entendi muito bem a query que você quer fazer mas seguindo este mesmo exemplo acredito que você possa obter sucesso.

```
UPDATE produtos 
SET produtos.fornecedor = (SELECT movimentacao.Fornecedor 
 FROM movimentacao WHERE movimentacao.Codigo = produtos.codigo
 ORDER BY movimentacao.Data DESC LIMIT 1
)
WHERE
 condicao
```

Answer (score 6):

Você precisa de um `UPDATE JOIN` neste caso:

```
UPDATE produtos 
   [INNER JOIN | LEFT JOIN] movimentacao ON produtos.codigo = movimentacao.Codigo
   SET produtos.fornecedor = movimentacao.Fornecedor
   WHERE condicao
```

O problema neste caso é que não dá pra usar `ORDER BY`. Teria que ver se um where resolveria no seu caso específico.

Para manter o `ORDER BY`, a solução seria uma subquery:

```
UPDATE produtos
   SET produtos.fornecedor = (
      SELECT movimentacao.Fornecedor
         FROM movimentacao
         WHERE produtos.codigo = movimentacao.Codigo
   )
   ORDER BY movimentacao.Data DESC
   LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Só teve um pequeno problema, o ORDER BY ficou fora do SELECT mas fora isso tudo bem.

Comment: O Order By fora é pra atualizar o mais recente. Dentro, como na resposta aprovada, não faz muito sentido, a não ser que tenha repetições, o que não está claro na pergunta. Mas dado o "histórico", entendo o accept perfeitamente. O bom é que você tenha solucionado o problema.

Comment: Sim, é que eu quero atualizar dos mas com os dados buscados mais recentes, mas o problema já foi resolvido valeu..

Answer (score 0):

Estou com uma duvida, preciso fazer a subtração de uma linha(quantidade) da tabela(vendas)que foi inserida pelo usuario no form, na tabela(produtos) na linha(estoque), sendo que tem que ser feito somente o do ultimo registro cadastrado na tabela(produtos). Fiz um form de cadastro da venda, onde ele insere os dados na tabela para registro, e depois criei um update para atualizar o valor do estoque(estoque-quantidade=estoque). Meu código php que estou usando foi esse:

```
     <?php 
include 'conexao.php';
$id = $_POST['id'] // Este id só existe na tabela de vendas, na tabela de produto é id_produtos
$cd_barras = $_POST["cd_barras"] // 
$nomeproduto =$_POST["nomeproduto"]
$preco_venda = $_POST["preco_venda"]
$quantidade = $_POST["quantidade"]
$tamanho = $_POST["tamanho"]

$decqtde = $quantidade ; // variável para subtração estoque-quantidade

$sql = "INSERT into vendaprodutos (cd_barras, nomeproduto, preco_venda, quantidade, tamanho) VALUES (NULL,'$cd_barras','$nomeproduto','$preco_venda','$quantidade','$tamanho')";
mysql_query($sql,);

$sql = "UPDATE produtos set produtos.estoque = vendaproduto.quantidade WHERE id = '$cd_barras'; "; 
mysql_query($sql); 

header("Location: venda.php");
?>
```

Podem meu ajudar, pois procurei em alguns fóruns e não consegui solucionar.

Comment: Bem Vindo, Thiago. Use o botão [Faça uma pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) que está na parte superior/direita da tela para fazer uma pergunta. O campo de respostas deve ser usado apenas para responder a pergunta. ;)

Comment: Obrigado, fiz a pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/73395/subtrair-linha-de-uma-tabela-por-outra-de-outra-tabela