# Subtrair linha de uma tabela por outra de outra tabela

Tags: php, mysql

Estou com uma dúvida. Preciso fazer a subtração de uma linha(quantidade) da tabela(vendas)que foi inserida pelo usuário no `form`, na tabela(produtos) na linha(estoque), sendo que tem que ser feito somente o do último registro cadastrado na tabela(produtos). Fiz um `form` de cadastro da venda, onde ele insere os dados na tabela para registro, e depois criei um `update` para atualizar o valor do estoque(estoque-quantidade=estoque). Meu código PHP que estou usando foi esse:

```
    <?php 
include 'conexao.php';
$id = $_POST['id'] // Este id só existe na tabela de vendas, na tabela de produto é id_produtos
$cd_barras = $_POST["cd_barras"] // 
$nomeproduto =$_POST["nomeproduto"]
$preco_venda = $_POST["preco_venda"]
$quantidade = $_POST["quantidade"]
$tamanho = $_POST["tamanho"]

$decqtde = $quantidade ; // variável para subtração estoque-quantidade

$sql = "INSERT into vendaprodutos (cd_barras, nomeproduto, preco_venda, quantidade, tamanho) VALUES (NULL,'$cd_barras','$nomeproduto','$preco_venda','$quantidade','$tamanho')";
mysql_query($sql,);

$sql = "UPDATE produtos set produtos.estoque = vendaproduto.quantidade WHERE id = '$cd_barras'; "; 
mysql_query($sql); 

header("Location: venda.php");
?>
```

Podem meu ajudar, pois procurei em alguns fóruns e não consegui solucionar.

Comment: Tentou usar o mysql_insert_id()? ele busca o último ID inserido, pra que você faça a subtração daquele produto, na quantidade... E você precisa setar variáveis diferentes para insert e update... Na minha opinião.

Answer (score 1):

Eu faria desta forma:

```
include 'conexao.php';

extract($_POST);

/* Lembrando que ao passar os posts, nas variaveis de insert, são as mesmas dos campos vinda no POST */
$sql_insert = mysql_query("
                INSERT INTO vendaprodutos 
                    (
                        cd_barras, nomeproduto, preco_venda, quantidade, tamanho
                    )
                VALUES
                    (
                        NULL,'{$cd_barras}','{$nomeproduto}','{$preco_venda}','{$quantidade}','{$tamanho}'
                    )
");

$sql_update = mysql_query("
                UPDATE produtos SET estoque = (quantidade - {$quantidade}) WHERE id '{$cd_barras}'
"); 

header("Location: venda.php");
```

## Nesta mudança a soma seria automática, tente desta forma.

Comment: Obrigado, irei fazer o teste.. mas só uma duvida, no caso as duas variveis que tu colocou: '$quantidade_atual //essa vem do post do form com o valor colocado pelo usuario certo?  e $qtde_atual // faz referencia ao que? '
no form de venda o usuário só informa a quantidade que quer do produto..

Comment: No mesmo form, você pode colocar a quantidade ATUAL desse produto.